# jQuery: Can't iterate

Tags: jquery, arrays, iteration

I am iterating over an table to pick out the form elements from each table row. What am I doing wrong in the below example?

```
var result = new Array();
var counter = 1;

$('tbody tr', this.el).each(function(){

    var inner = new Array();

    $('input',this).each(function(){
        console.log(this.name, $(this).val());  // Works: sends name/value to console!
        inner[this.name] = $(this).val(); // Appears to be empty
    });

    result[counter] = inner;
    counter++;
});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Try removing the 'this.el' in $().

Comment: Nope, that's not it. I am iterating over a current element in a `backbone.js`-view and the results are there when I access them by `console.log` but won't get appended to my array...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're doing arrays wrong.

In Javascript, an Array is a special case of object which has *numeric keys only* and has an interface defined by functions like `push`:

```
var myArray = [];
myArray.push("first element");
myArray.push("second element");
myArray.push("third element");
```

You're making the very common mistake of trying to use an array like a more generic object, assigning *string keys* and using `x[y] = z` notation in order to do so. It's a hack that sometimes may happen to seem to work, but is *not how arrays are supposed to be used*.

You have the same problem with `inner` and with `result`.

Instead, use the generic object that you were attempting to use in the first place:

```
var result  = {};     // <!-- create new _object_
var counter = 1;

$('tbody tr', this.el).each(function() {

    var inner = {};   // <!-- create new _object_

    $('input', this).each(function() {
        var val = this.value;

        console.log(this.name, val);
        inner[this.name] = val;
    });

    result[counter] = inner;
    counter++;
});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

use

```
var inner = {};
```

instead of

```
var inner = new Array();
```

than iterate with `for-in` statement

also for the `results` should be the same, or use `results.push()` but in this case `counter` not need to be used because of index is set automatically

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var result = new Array();
var counter = 1;
var inctr = 0;

$('tbody tr', this.el).each(function(){

    var inner = new Array();
    inctr = 0;

    $('input',this).each(function(){
        console.log(this.name, $(this).val());  // Works: sends name/value to console!
        inctr++;
        inner[inctr] = $(this).val(); // Appears to be empty
    });

    result[counter] = inner;
    counter++;
});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not initiate object variable inside a loop put it before the loop to improve the performance.

Good luck!!